# Qt Installer framework - Customizing the UNINSTALLER

Tags: qt, uninstallation, qt-installer

I am not able to get a hold of customizing the un-installation process, though I could succeed to some extent customizing the installation process. When I register for the signals “installationFinished” my functions in the installscript.qs gets called, but surprisingly the signals “uninstallationStarted and uninstallationFinished” never gets called if I register some functions. Not sure why? Also in qinstaller.h we have the below code for identifying different state/stages of installation, but how can I get similar information for un-installation?

```
enum Status {
    InstallerUnfinished,
    InstallerCanceledByUser,
    InstallerRunning,
    InstallerFailed,
    InstallerSucceeded,
};
int status() const;

enum WizardPage {
    Introduction = 0x1000,
    TargetDirectory = 0x2000,
    ComponentSelection = 0x3000,
    LicenseCheck = 0x4000,
    StartMenuSelection = 0x5000,
    ReadyForInstallation = 0x6000,
    PerformInstallation = 0x7000,
    InstallationFinished = 0x8000,
    End = 0xffff
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you try this?

```
function Controller()
{
    installer.uninstallationStarted.connect(this, Controller.prototype.runMyFunc);
}

Controller.prototype.runMyFunc = function()
{
 // your code here
}
```